# Application: Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

We have two collections of random variables $X_i$ and $Y_i$. The $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed with expectation $1$, and the $Y_i$ are also independent and identically distributed with expectation $2$. We first flip a coin once, and we define, for all $n$, a random variable $S_n$ by $S_n=\sum_iX_i$  if heads comes up, and $S_n = \sum_iY_i$ if tail comes up. Show that

(a) $E(\frac{S_n}{n})=\frac{3}{2}$.

(b) $P\left(\left|\frac{S_n}{n} − \frac{3}{2}\right| > \frac{1}{4}\right)$ does not converge to $0$, when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

(c) Why does (b) not contradict the law of large numbers?

I was able to show a, but I'm not sure on how to show $b$ and $c$. Any help would be wonderful!

Answer (score 4):

You can consider the special case $X_i \equiv 1,Y_i \equiv 2$. Then $S_n/n$ is either $1$ or $2$ with probability $1$. But there is no contradiction because $S_n$ is not itself a sum of iid random variables.

Comment: thank you for the insight. Isn't Sn by definition (based on the way the question was set up) a sum of either random variables $Xi$'s or $Yi$'s, which are both iid

Comment: @user320559 Yes, but it's not literally given by a single sum of iids, which makes it a different situation. Intuitively, there is no averaging out of the the variance due to the initial coin flip, which survives in the limit $n \to \infty$.

Comment: so the fact that Sn could be the sum of either Xi's or Yi's, means that Sn/n can't never be defined as the single mean as n goes to infinity?